# Do action once but only repeat it after x time

Tags: php, repeat

So basically, i need to notify a user if:

a) sensor disconnects and there hasn't been an alarm sent in last $send_threshold

b) if alarm sent on same day and greater than $repeat_threshold.

**Example values of the variables**

```
$send_threshold = 12 * 60; // 12 min

$repeat_threshold = 2 * 60 * 60 + 45 * 60; // 2 hr 45 min
```

I'm drawing a complete blank on how to make it happen. The sensors are stateless so there is no way for me to check if a sensor is online, other than to check timestamps of received data that the sensor posted to the api.

```
/* FUNCTIONS */
function handleDisconnectAlerts($sensor,$dataset,$users,$settings)
{
    end($dataset);
    $last_timestamp = $dataset[key($dataset)]['timestamp'];
    $now = time();
    if($now > $last_timestamp && $now - $last_timestamp > $settings['disconnect_alarm'] * 60)
    {
        $send_threshold = $settings['disconnect_alarm'] * 60;
        $repeat_threshold = $settings['disconnect_alarm_repeat_hours'] * 60 * 60 + $settings['disconnect_alarm_repeat_minutes'] * 60;

        //not really sure what to do from here.

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i figured it out myself i guess. The initial check covers the intial interval of `60 * $settings['disconnect_alarm']`. From there i just needed to check that an alarm hasn't been sent in `$repeat_threshold` time. Works like a charm.

```
function handleDisconnectAlerts($sensor,$dataset,$users,$settings)
{
    end($dataset);
    $last_timestamp = $dataset[key($dataset)]['timestamp'];
    $now = time();
    if($now > $last_timestamp && $now - $last_timestamp > $settings['disconnect_alarm'] * 60)
    {
        $repeat_threshold = $settings['disconnect_alarm_repeat_hours'] * 60 * 60 + $settings['disconnect_alarm_repeat_minutes'] * 60;
        $n_sent = R::count('sensoralerts',' timestamp >=:time and field_name="disconnect" and sensor_id=:id ',
            [':time'=>$repeat_threshold,':id'=>$sensor['id']]
        );
        if($n_sent == 0){
            multiSendDisconnect($users,$sensor);
        }
    }
}
```